# How to return all keywords in a map

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I want to return all the keywords appeared in map. For instance:

```
{:a 1 :d 4 :e 4}
```

I want to get (:a :d :e). my code is

```
(get {:a 1 :d 4 :e 4} :keywords)
```

It returns nil. So how to fix it?

Comment: What output would you like if your map was `{:a :b, :d 4, 5 :e, 7 [8 :f :g]}`?

Comment: It hardly makes sense to ask for the *keywords* from a map. The `keys` of a map can be any values - numbers, strings, collections of any kind. Keywords are often chosen because they are easy literals that are fast to look up. You can even have functions as keys, though this is seldom useful, as functions are equal only if identical.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you want to get all the `keys` from your map. You can do that using:

```
(keys {:a 1, :d 4, :e 4}
;; => (:a :d :e)
```

If you would like to get all the **keywords** when they appear as keys in a map you need to `filter` only those matching `keyword?` predicate:

```
(filter keyword? (keys {:a 1, 'd 4, :e 4, "f" 5}))
;; => (:a :e)
```

Similarly for keywords from map values:

```
(filter keyword? (vals {:a :b, "c" :d, 4 "e", 5 'f}))
;; => (:b :d)
```